# Getting an error when using the results of api search made with pinia

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, pinia

i'm learning vue 3 and I did a page that using pinia searches a user using github api and show the results on the page.
I'm getting the results and putting it on the page, its all working perfectly, but it's showing an error on vscode, that i think is of type since i'm using typescript.
[image]

How should i been doing it? Should I declare the type of this results before I use them? I'm really starting on this so how should I do it?

here is the code of the page:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref, computed } from "vue";
import { useUserStore } from "../stores/users";

const isActive = ref(false);

const store = useUserStore();
const searchUser = ref("");

const handleSearch = () => {
  store.fetchUsers(searchUser.value);
  isActive.value = true;
};

const getUsers = computed(() => {
  return store.getUsers;
});
</script>

<template>
  <div class="search">
    <form action="" @submit.prevent="handleSearch">
      <input
        class="search-input"
        placeholder="Find GitHub User"
        type="text"
        v-model="searchUser"
      />
      <button class="search-button" type="submit">
        <img class="search-img" src="../assets/search.svg" />
      </button>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="result" v-if="isActive">
    <div class="result-container">
      <img class="result-img" :src="store.users.avatar_url" alt="" />
      <div>
        <h3 class="result-name">
          Nome:
          <a class="result-link" target="_blank" :href="store.users.html_url">
            {{ store.users.name }}
          </a>
        </h3>
        <h4 class="result-user">Usuário: {{ store.users.login }}</h4>
        <p>{{ store.users.public_repos }} repositórios públicos</p>
        <p>Seguidores: {{ store.users.followers }}  |  Seguindo: {{ store.users.following }}</p>
        <p>Local: {{ store.users.location }}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

And here the store with pinia:

```
import { defineStore } from "pinia";
import axios from "axios";

export const useUserStore = defineStore("user", {
  state: () => ({
    users: [{}],
  }),
  getters: {
    getUsers(state) {
      return state.users;
    },
  },
  actions: {
    async fetchUsers(inputValue: string) {
      try {
        const data = await axios.get(
          `https://api.github.com/users/${inputValue}`
        );
        
        this.users = data.data;
        // console.log("users", (users));
      } catch (error) {
        alert(error);
        console.log(error);
      }
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: yes, it's a typescript only issue.  it's still valid javascript so your app still works, but the point of typescript is to enforce proper types.  As far as typescript is concerned, `state.users` type is literally `{}[]` (empty object array).  If you give it a proper type, the error will go away.  Pinia has some good [documentation](https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/state.html#typescript) regarding typing your state.

Comment: Thank you, i'll have a look at it